# What is a word for people I follow?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

I want to know the word for person or group of people that I follow.
I tried searching on the internet and found nothing.

Comment: Google has thousands of instances of [*my **feeds** on Twitter*](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22my%20feeds%20on%20twitter%22), for example. And I suspect that's the best you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context the person or group can have different names:

1. [**Followee**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/followee) [**[followees](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/followees#English)** - plural] - A person who is being tracked on a social media website or application; A person who is being followed.
2. [**Leader**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leader) - The person who leads or commands a group, organization, or country; One who guides others in action or opinion; one who takes the lead in any business, enterprise, or movement; one who is ‘followed’.
3. [**Guide**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guide) - A person who shows the way to others, especially one employed to show tourists around places of interest.

This person can also be a commanding officer (CO) in the context of missions, a conductor, maybe a profile or an account.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general term for this in English other than *leader*, but social media has given a new meaning to the term *follow*, meaning to subscribe to status updates, and you can't call the person you're following a leader in this case.

Depending on your context you may be able to use the terms *publish/subscribe* or even *publish/follow* but that is unlikely to be understood by many social media users.  However, a term that might work across multiple such services is *account*, since it can be said you follow both a Facebook and Twitter account, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the word followee seems OK, but it's little usage to mean the person you follow.

The leader of the religious sect and 30 of his followers killed themselves in a suicide pact last  - Cambridge Dictionary

I think the word leader is approriate and most common.